# "The requested URL was not found on this server" error in laravel php project

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, routes, frameworks

I started to develop a project with laravel. I installed it using this link [how-to-install-laravel-on-ubuntu-lamp](http://tutsnare.com/how-to-install-laravel-on-ubuntu-lamp/).

I installed `composer` successfully, and using this command : `sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel /home/egz-pc/laravel-project` I created new project named `laravel-project` then a changed permissions using chmod 777 command.I restart apache and execute my project.

My problem is that when I type in browser: http://localhost/laravel-project I'm getting an error: `The requested URL /laravel-project was not found on this server.`  If I create a project in /var/www/html on my local host I have no problems, and that error does not appear. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Apache server is installed on var/www/html.This is the default root directory of apache.

Either change the root directory of Apache or move the project to var/www/html.

To change Apache's root directory,

Run

```
 cd /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Then open the 000-default.conf file using the command

```
 nano 000-default.conf
```

Edit the DocumentRoot

[image]

Then restart the apache server

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

---

If you get "Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server"  after changing the root of apache then do follow these steps

1.Find the apache2.conf located in etc/apache2 and open it using

```
 nano apache2.conf
```

2.Use ctrl+w and search for Directory (It should be in line 153)

3.It should look like this

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

4.Change it to

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

[image]
5.Restart apache2 and it should work.

EDIT:

I have made a script that lets you change Apache root directory in 1 command.

Link: [Script for Apache](https://github.com/hsb4995/Apachange)

Comment: Thanks! I changed that file and now I'm having another problem : Forbidden, You don't have permission to access / on this server. Even that the project have 777 permision and also i removed root and i put: drwxrwxrwx 11 www-data  www-data  4096 Sht  4 13:09 laravel-project?